# MySQL combine two column with three columns

Tags: mysql

I want to combine two table2 in one table.

I have tried to use union in MySQL, but it not succesfully.

My coding:

```
Select  id,name;
union all
select id, name,sex;
```

Sample data:

Table_1

```
ID, Name
--------
1   JJ   
3   PP
```

Table 2

```
ID, Name, Sex
-------------
33  A     M
22  B     F
```

Result that I needs should look like:

```
ID, Name, Sex,
 1   JJ   
 3   PP
33    A     M
22    B     F
```

Can we do that in mysql store procedure ?

Comment: What does the theoretical definition of UNION ALL says ?

Answer (score 0):

Number of columns and their types of two resultsets combined with `UNION [ALL]` should be the same. That being said try

```
SELECT  id, name, NULL sex
  FROM Table1
 UNION ALL
SELECT id, name, sex
  FROM Table2
```

Output:

```
| ID | NAME |    SEX |
----------------------
|  1 |   JJ | (null) |
|  3 |   PP | (null) |
| 33 |    A |      M |
| 22 |    B |      F |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b224/1)** demo

Further reading

- [UNION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html)

> *Can we do that in mysql store procedure?*

Yes, you can if you have to.

Comment: Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Answer (score 0):

When using the 'UNION' operator in a sql statement the two combined tables (result sets) must have the same number and type of columns. Otherwise the statement will fail, since the server cannot decide *how* to combine the two tables. 
So you need to artificially create a third column for the frist table, so that its set of columns matches thse in the second table:

```
SELECT  id,name,'' AS sex FROM Table_1 UNION SELECT id, name, sex FROM Table_2
```